# Rootless CLI Utilities

Tags: applications, terminal, command-line

Do I have to root my android device to install command line utilities? I would really like to run [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), among other programs on my phone. I have no reason not to root my phone, I just want to know if this is possible.

The [Android Scripting](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) seems to possibly have done this. Do I have to write my own Terminal app to be able to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need root.  You also don't need a terminal, for an app to use its own private utilities.  But if you want vim, [Terminal IDE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en) provides that, a number of other utilities (git, ssh, tmux), the ability to use bash or Java as a 'scripting language' at the terminal, and the ability to create and install Android apps on-device.  I use Terminal IDE and vim quite a bit, (but with Better Terminal Emulator Pro's terminal, actually.)

Comment: What's the correct way to run Terminal IDE's bash from "adb shell"? Running it manually "su; /data/data/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside/files/system/bin/bash" leaves a slightly broken env.

Answer (score 1):

Rooting your phone gives you root access (duh!), but that doesn't mean accessing a shell requires you to root your phone.  You can use [ADB](https://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) to connect to your device and gain shell access.

You can also use [ConnectBot](https://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) to access your device's shell on the device itself.

This will give you normal access to your device and you will not be able to run `su` to gain root access.  You can, however, modify and play with files to which you have access.

`vim` is available without root access, so, so far you still have no reason to root your phone.