# How can I force-stop all user applications that are running?

Tags: applications, force-stop

I found that first of all System>Apps>Running is not helpful always and secondly I we stop the services, it may star again if corresponding application is running. The correct way to stop application is **force stop**. (that's why ram booster may not helpful sufficiently).

I've made an simple script that get the list of all user applications and then force-stop all one by one:

```
pm list packages -3 -f | sed /jackpal.androidterm/d > /sdcard/tbs/app2fs

while read -r line; do APK=$(echo $line | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d '=' -f1); PKG=$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f2); echo "Forcing to Stop: $(aapt d badging $APK | grep "application: label" | cut -d "'" -f2)"; am force-stop $PKG; done < /sdcard/tbs/app2fs
```

The draw back of above command is it tries to force-stops all (doesn't matter running or not) third-party applications. But I want to do `am force-stop` only for the running user apps.

So, **How do I get the list of all running user apps (not services)?**

You may have better way to do this than my script/command, hence broadly: **How can I force-stop all user applications that are running?**

Note: I recommend the command-line solution. Because this type application (that can force-stop all running user apps) mostly runs constantly for monitoring which I don't like. If you've a suggestion for an app that can do such job and also favourable (should not run constantly for monitory) , then you can suggest it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: This solution:

- is tested on Android 4.2.1 and 5.0.2 (COS12);
- requires a rooted device with Busybox installed and latter's applets available under PATH variable. You may see [How do I install missing command line tools onto an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/134588/96277)

---

If an app is running (be it in background or foreground) then it must have a process assigned to it. In that case, it should show up under the radar of *ps* command. We can single out apps' processes from *ps* command and compare them with the list stored from *pm* command. Whatever comes out as common can be safely killed.

Here's a basic script to do that:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

HOME="/data/media/0";
mkfifo "$HOME"/ps "$HOME"/packages;
/system/bin/ps | grep 'u0_' | awk '{print$9}' | sort -o "$HOME"/ps &
pm list packages -3 | sed 's/package://g' | sort -o "$HOME/"packages &
comm -12 "$HOME"/ps "$HOME"/packages | while read package; do am force-stop "$package"; printf "Force-stopped: $package\n"; done
rm "$HOME"/ps "$HOME"/packages;
```

This script must be run with root privilege.

In that script:

- I'm creating two [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), namely *ps* and *packages* under `/data/media/0`. (It is optional to do. You can safely remove the lines starting with `mkfifo` and `rm`). I'm relying on the output provided by native *ps* tool. If an app has a process, then its package name would be shown under the column *NAME*. I'm using grep to filter out processes running under user 0 (your user account has user ID 0) and then using *awk* to print the 9th field. That field in each line would show a package name.

  **Note** that you can use Busybox's *ps* tool. It has a feature to show only a particular column. You'll have to tweak the script a bit but you can do away with hard-coded dependency (a particular field in a line).
- I'm storing a list of user-installed packages (third-party) using *pm* tool.
- I'm now comparing the content of *ps* and *packages* and listing only the common lines. **Note** that I used *sort* in earlier commands because *comm* requires a sorted file.

  Each common line then goes through a loop where the line (a package name) is used to force-stop the corresponding package.

**Note**: `am force-stop` is useless against a device administrator app.

Comment: How did I miss `ps`!