# How can I find my MAC address?

Tags: settings, mac-address

I'm using a Samsung Young Duos GT-S6102.  My phone that shows nothing in Settings → About Phone so my question is how to find my MAC address?

Comment: Enable Wi-Fi and then check.

Comment: Have you checked `Settings => About => Status`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run `ip address` from a terminal or `adb shell` to get the MAC address.  Specifically, `ip address show wlan0` will give you the MAC for the Wi-Fi chip on most devices.  The address is shown after `link/ether` on the second line:

```
22: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
link/ether a0:b1:c2:d3:e4:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.0.12/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
inet6 ab01::c23d:45ef:ab67:89c0/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Thanks to [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord) for this suggestion.

---

Another alternative:

If you have [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) installed, you can run `busybox ifconfig`.  That will give output similar to the following (note the `HWaddr` on the first line):

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A0:B1:C2:D3:E4:F5
          inet addr:192.168.0.12  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: ab01::c23d:45ef:ab67:89c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:993 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:747 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:904409 (883.2 KiB)  TX bytes:125749 (122.8 KiB)
```

If you don't have busybox you could try running `ifconfig` alone, but the version on my device has no output (and `ifconfig wlan0` just shows the IP address).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the solutions from [Matthew](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/142630/96277) and [Vivek](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/142641/96277), using a terminal emulator app or using `adb shell`, do

```
getprop ro.boot.wifimacaddr
```

It would give you the MAC address for your wireless chip.

Alternatively, check the contents of the file [/sys/class/net/wlan0/address](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net):

```
cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address
```

That should give you the MAC address. Make sure you have your Wi-Fi turned on before you see the contents of that file. For some reason, I got a different MAC address when Wi-Fi was turned off in my stock Android 6.0.1

If you've [BusyBox](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/134593/96277) installed, you can also do:

```
busybox iplink show wlan0
```

Output:

```
5: wlan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
link/ether 3c:42:66:c4:d5:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Again, keep Wi-Fi enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Check settings > WiFi . From there click three dot or option key and navigate to advance settings. There you will find Mac address of your device.